# Update One List of Objects Attribute with Other List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario as think

```
class a 
{
  String Username;
  String val;
}


 List<a> lst = new List<a>();

 List<a> lstnew = new List<a>();
```

What i required is to that in `lstnew` i have some updated values in `val` Attribute **(Only in Several Objects)** , what i required is to update the `lst` with updated values in `lstnew` as the `Username` Attribute using **LINQ**

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired, but I failed to understand a single word of your question.

Comment: Its like with `List<a>` and `List<b>` are there and `List<a>` and List<b> has same usernames but Different `Val` for `Some` usernames .. I need to set these Different `Val` in `List<b>` to `List<a>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can join the two lists on `UserName`, and then update the `Value`s in the first list with those in the second.

For example, given this class and lists:

```
public class a
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

List<a> list = new List<a>
{
    new a { UserName = "Perry", Value = "A" },
    new a { UserName = "Ferb", Value = "B" },
    new a { UserName = "Phineas", Value = "C" }
};

List<a> newList = new List<a>
{
    new a { UserName = "Phineas", Value = "X" },
    new a { UserName = "Ferb", Value = "Y" },
    new a { UserName = "Candace", Value = "Z" }
};
```

You can join to get the elements with common `UserName`s:

```
var common = from a1 in list
             join a2 in newList on a1.UserName equals a2.UserName
             select new { A1 = a1, A2 = a2 };
```

At this point, if I understand you correctly, you want to update the elements from the original list:

```
foreach(var c in common)
{
    c.A1.Value = c.A2.Value;
}
```

at which point the elements in `list` look like:

```
UserName    Value
-----------------
Perry       A
Ferb        Y
Phineas     X
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. God bless you adrift.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have two lists.  One of which is named `lst` and contains a full list of usernames and a second one named `lstnew` that contains a list of usernames who have had their `val` property updated.  I suggest unioning the untouched usernames with the ones that have been updated.  This represents the most LINQ-friendly solution I can think of.

```
var updatedList = Enumerable.Union(
    lst.Where(x => !lstnew.Any(y => y.Username == x.Username)),
    lstnew).ToList();
```

Comment: Its like with `List<a>` and `List<b>` are there and `List<a>` and List<b> has same usernames but Different `Val` for `Some` usernames .. I need to set these Different `Val` in `List<b>` to `List<a>`

Comment: Why not just copy the list then?  `var lstnew = lst.ToList()`

Comment: List<b> only has updated values not ALL the values only which updated

Comment: I updated my answer based off of this clarification.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use the [`.Zip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method to execute this.

```
lst.Zip(lstNew, (orig, new) => {
    orig.Username = new.Username;
    return orig;
});
```

the idea that you are getting each pair together, then instead of returning a new one, changing the `orig.Username` value and return the `orig`.

Answer (score 0):

This should also do the trick. `Zip` method, propsed by Alastair Pitts assumes that both collections have the same order of elements and each element from first list has correspondent element in second list. My approach is more generic, it simply looks for corresponding element by comparing `Username` property. Still it assumes that for each element in `lstNew` there is corresponding element in `lst`.

```
lstNew.ForEach(new => lst.First(orig => orig.Username == new.Username).val = new.val);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but a more elegant solution that I have developed, which is a slight improvement over the one given by @JeffOgata would be:

```
var newList= lst.GroupJoin(lstnew ,
                i => i.UserName ,
                j => j.UserName ,
                (i, j) => j.FirstOrDefault()?? i );
```

Where `lst` is the original list and `lstnew` is the new list.

This will just replace the entire object in the first list with the corresponding object in the second list (the join) if one exists. 
It is a slight improvement over the answer given by @JeffOgata

The result is the same.

If you have complex objects then iterating through each object then going through all the properties was a problem, simply replacing the old object with the new one was quicker.

This hopefully will help someone.